# How do I mass rename only part of file names?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Ive got hundreds of files I need to rename. Currently they look something like this:

```
localhost.programA.programA1.programA1stuff
```

and I want to change it to

```
unixServer.programA.programA1.programA1stuff
```

As you can see, I just want to change the first portion of the file name to be the new host name. I am new-ish to unix/linux so Im not sure if there is an easy way to do this that isnt by hand.  I imagine that there is some kind of crazy awk/sed one liner that could do this, but I am not remotely familiar with either one of those tools to even know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "rename" command.

In your case :

```
rename localhost unixServer ./localhost*
```

You can be more specific if you want.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html

Comment: Oh, well that was fairly uneventful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, rename command just worked for me.

```
root@H61H2-MV:~/3# for i in {a..e} ; do touch localhost.program$i.program$i1.program$i1stuff ; done
root@:~/# ls
localhost.programa.program.program  localhost.programd.program.program
localhost.programb.program.program  localhost.programe.program.program
localhost.programc.program.program
root@technomics-H61H2-MV:~/# rename 's/localhost/unixServer/' localhost.*
root@H61H2-MV:~/# ls
unixServer.programa.program.program  unixServer.programd.program.program
unixServer.programb.program.program  unixServer.programe.program.program
unixServer.programc.program.program
root@H61H2-MV:~/#
```

Rename command syntax as I used, will work like charm for your requirement.. give it a try..

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
$ find . -iname "localhost*"
./localhost.programA.programA1.programA1stuff

$ find . -iname "localhost*" | while read file; do mv $file ${file/localhost/unixserver}; done

$ find . -iname "unixserver*"
./unixserver.programA.programA1.programA1stuff
```